# Method invocation is skipped in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, resharper, global-asax, resharper-7.1

I have this simple code :

```
 void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Trace.Write("Exception Handling", "......");
    }
```

However re-sharper scream (no-error only suggest) about :

[image]

> Method invocation is skipped. Compiler will not generate method
>   invocation because the method is conditional, or it is a partial
>   method without implementation

I'm not able to see this line in the Trace output.

however - other traces - I do see.

Why is that ?

(p.s. The page (which is under web Site project) has  `trace="true"`).

Comment: `trace==true` is not related to TRACE

Comment: @HenkHolterman What do you mean ? `<%@ Page Trace="true" %>` allows me to trace. ( can you please explain ?)

Comment: Remove `using System.Diagnostics;`

Comment: @HenkHolterman I  removed it and now I wrote only `Context.Trace.Write("34343");`  but http://i.stack.imgur.com/qlAST.jpg

Comment: I don't click on picture-links.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Ok. (it's just the trace output.). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Why did you delete your UTF-8 question a few minutes ago? I think I found some usefull information for it.

Comment: @SonerGönül because I was fool enough not to look for it in  wikipedia which shows how its done....

Comment: @RoyiNamir Ok. Just want to say there is some usefull information also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377.aspx

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Be sure that the `TRACE` constant is defined in your project settings for your current build configuration.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Since it's a website project, you could put

```
#define TRACE
```

at the top of `Global.asax.cs` so that the trace symbol is defined.

Comment: I'm in web site...it doesnt have this menu.

Comment: @RoyiNamir updated, sorry, didn't know it was a web site project at first

Comment: @RoyiNamir if you were to use the #define, it'd have to go in `Global.asax.cs` not in a script block in `Global.asax`

Comment: global.asax in website doesnt have cs.

Comment: You can add a code-behind. But since Trace is not recommended for ASP.NET it's all a bit academic.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Hi. I did added a cs file and in global.asax I added `<%@ Application Language="C#" Inherits="myClass" %>` and not it doesnt yell. However - I dont see the line in the trace report. Does trace can't handle info from the http moudle pipeline ( global asax events) ?

Comment: Which trace report? I think you're confusing 2 systems. Diagnostics.Trace != TraceContext.

Comment: Could `Context.Trace.Write(...);` be what you're looking for instead? (in your Global.asax) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.tracecontext.aspx

Comment: I added this line ( and remove diagnostics) but http://i.stack.imgur.com/qlAST.jpg

Comment: I had to check Define DEBUG constant too mot only Define TRACE constant

Comment: For those who got here and are still scratching their heads: make sure the TRACE constant is turned on in the project that needs it, not necessarily the one that's calling it. For instance, in our solution, one project implemented a TraceListener, and another project created a TraceSource and added the listener. The TRACE constant was on in the project with the TraceSource, but not the one with the custom listener, so it failed to write to the affected listener while writing to the others. Tricky, tricky!

Answer (score 2):

To quote [the JetBrains wiki](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/Method+invocation+is+skipped) (which may* be linked to from the ReSharper menu under 'Why is ReSharper suggesting this'):

> While coding, you may encounter warnings regarding methods whose
>   invocations will not be generated by the compiler. Why would that be?
>   Typical cases are conditional methods that will not be compiled (e.g.,
>   it’s marked with `[ReSharperInt:Conditional("DEBUG")]` and you’re in
>   `RELEASE` mode). Another reason why a method may be skipped is that,
>   at some point, its body has been declared as `partial` and the
>   implementation wasn’t provided.

Given that this is on a method of `Trace`, I'd suggest the first of these typical cases is the one that applies.

<sup><sub>* I haven't got v7 yet</sub></sup>

Comment: 1) my global asax file is not partial . 2)I;m in debug mode.